# Try to change Printer of my old application windows fourm

Tags: c#, decompiler

I designed a Windows form application many years ago, and due to my lack of experience in programming and not following some professional programming tips to debug it, also I have lost the project source code. I know I had statically defined the printer name in the software, how can I access my source code?

```
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified.

   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   at MehrPouyan.ServiceForm.SendPrint()
   at MehrPouyan.ServiceForm.btnPrint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Are you asking about [assembly] language, like changing the machine code?  If so, you haven't shown any.  Or did you mean to tag [.net-assembly]?  If so, you haven't said anything about any specific .NET assembly.

Comment: dear @PeterCordes thanks for your comment, just ask any idea for solving it with assembly or registry or another way for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by decompiling my software and used this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile